# Don't understand how increaseuserva works

Tags: windows-7, memory

I've got 4GB of ram on my laptop, but my operating system is Windows 7 x86 so I've got 3~ GB available from 4GB.

Some games are crashing because of running out of memory. 
So the solution I found is to use `bcdedit/ set IncreaseUserVA 3072`. I still haven't used it because I've got a question - How does it work?

I mean - it allows applications to get memory from `non-visible` 1GB or what?

Comment: What this command is well documented: http://superuser.com/questions/253132/what-are-the-dangers-of-manually-setting-increaseuserva

Comment: @Ramhound But so out of 4 GB it's means that those 1 GB is actually in use for OS? And they are not visible not because they are not available for OS? Because it does not give explanation how it works when I've got 3 GB and 4 GB RAM installed in x86 system

Comment: "The "bcedit /set IncreaseUserVA 3072" command changes the partitioning so that each program gets 3GB and kernel space only gets 1GB."  What is confusing about that?

Comment: @Ramhound but from where it gets 3GB? If I've got 3GB ram and use this command - what will happen?

Answer (score 0):

You mix virtual and physical memory management. By default 32Bit processes can use 2GB of **virtual** memory. By running this command applications can now see 3GB of virtual memory on a 32Bit Windows and 4GB of virtual memory on a 64Bit Windows when the application is compiled with the [/LARGEADDRESSAWARE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z.aspx) linker option.